# How Can I Expose to Outside My Services on Azure?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, load-balancing, azure-aks, azure-load-balancer

I have Azure Kubernetes cluster and i want to expose my services.How can i expose them with 1 IP and nodePorts ? My services using TCP so i can not use ingress.I do not want to buy an external Load Balancer for every service.Is there a way to achieve this on Azure ?

Answer (score 2):

> If there are external IPs that route to one or more cluster nodes, Kubernetes Services can be exposed on those externalIPs. Traffic that ingresses into the cluster with the external IP (as destination IP), on the Service port, will be routed to one of the Service endpoints. externalIPs are not managed by Kubernetes and are the responsibility of the cluster administrator.

you can use [external-ips](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#external-ips) to access your application with  `http://External_IP:ServicePort`

Comment: It may be a solution but i wonder about if there is a solution like NodePort ? It can be one load balancer that redirect traffic to backend nodeports.

Comment: I am not sure about the nodePort. You only need one externalIP and multiple application with different svc port .